# What element would the hemoglobin content of methane-based life use?

Tags: science-based, creature-design, aliens, xenobiology

So to start, let's assume that this hypothetical life form relied on something similar to LNG (liquefied natural gas) - mainly relying on ethane - as a solvent in the same way humans rely on water. Let's also assume that they breathe hydrogen, use acetylene as glucose, expel methane, and that they are carbon based like us.

Knowing that they do not use oxygen, what element makes for the optimal choice in acting as a hydrogen carrier at cryogenic temperatures, in the same way hemoglobin uses iron to act as an oxygen carrier?

Comment: acetylene as glucose - nice!

Comment: Chemical reactions don't occur at −182.8 °C, so your question is unanswerable.

Comment: Fine. Then what temperature range can intelligent, methane-based life function at?

Comment: @RonJohn Respectfully, that's *bullcrap*. Chemical reactions useful to *our* kind of life may proceed uselessly slowly at those temperatures without proper catalysis, but a wide variety of chemical reactions most assuredly still happen.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley if it's bullcrap, then present citation(s) of what chemical reactions *do* take place at that temperature.

Comment: @Wildcat who says that methane-base life *can* function?

Comment: Polymerization and tholin formation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tholin#Tholins_on_Triton.2C_Pluto.2C_and_Kuiper_belt_objects
Formation & decomposition of FOOF, and oxidation (sometimes violent) of *nearly anything else* by FOOF: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dioxygen_difluoride
Azatozome formation: https://thisscienceiscrazy.wordpress.com/2015/03/18/how-alien-cell-membranes-could-form-in-methane-seas/

Comment: @RonJohn 
And that's just off the top of my head. If some enterprising chemist wanted to make a career out of investigating low-temperature chemistry in hydrocarbon solvents, I bet they'd find oodles of interesting reactions.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley the uber-reactive FOOF decompose at the oh-so rapid rate of **4% per day** at −160 °C.  That's pretty damned slow.

Comment: @RonJohn So what? You said chemical reactions don't occur at those temperatures, when they manifestly *do*. The *rate* at which they occur was not at issue. So cold life might have to run slowly--so what? So it runs slowly. Or maybe there are catalysts that'll speed it up, just like *our* biology has catalysts that speed up reactions that go glacially slow on their own at *our* temperatures.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley technically, we only know that FOOF slowly docomposes at −160°C, whereas I wrote, "−182.8°C", but I see your point.  However, **OP is looking for intelligent life** at liquid methane temperatures (that's what he asked for in a comment on May 16), instead of "life that metabolizes much too slow to be interesting", then he should ask chemistry.SE what reaction happen fast enough to be interesting while slow enough to be non-explosive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like the premise!

Your critters could use a metal hydride.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_metal_hydride

You would need to bake up some heme ring equivalent to carry the hydride metal and control its uptake / release of hydrogen.

Or how about oxygen!  You could have a large ether in which the oxygen reversibly forms an alcohol, accepting and donating the hydrogen.

Comment: Chemical reactions would be **really slow** at that temperature (if they even happen at all).